# symfony2 use route id in access control

Tags: security, symfony

I am using Symfony2 framework with FOSUserBundle.

I am trying to allow anonymous users to access registration confirmation page, in order to validate own email.

So in my access control list i have the following entry.

```
access_control:
    - ...
    - { path: ^/register/confirm, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - ...
```

Please note that only administrators can input users (no free registration is possible in my case).

However, this is not very flexible.
Is it possible to use route id in order to identify the path to secure? In other words, in my case is it possible to have something like this?

```
access_control:
    - ...
    - { path: fos_user_registration_confirm, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - ...
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The first way you've proposed is right, and i think it's rather flexible. As far as you have only one `security.yml` file per project, it isn't much work to do some changes to it when you redefine your routes.